# Resize a div that's rotated by a transform matrix

Tags: html, css, matrix, transform

I've created the following div that's rotated -90deg by a transform matrix:

```html
<div id="container" style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; left: 50px; top: 50px; width: 200px; height: 283px; transform: matrix(0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0);">
    <div id="image" style="background-image: url(https://treditionservice.azurewebsites.net/api/file/show/coveruserimages/N2QzOTUxNjQtODAzYS00MjMxLWIxZDYtNzdkODNlZTc2MGU3LUNWLWYwYWZjN2IxLWFmNmItNGE1My1iZGI1LWY5Y2M0YTU2ZjFmYy0xM2I0YzY0OC0yZDc4LTRkY2MtODY4Ny1lYzU5NTRhMWExNDMuc3Zn/Kg==/Kg==/1/true);opacity:1;filter: blur(0px);background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: 100% 100%;width: 100%;height: 100%;"></div>
</div>
```

What I want to do is to resize the image container at the bottom right corner to any other pixel size. The aspect ratio of the image is not important. Of course, if I change width or height in container div, it will behave the opposite way because it's the behavior of the unrotated div.

Then I hoped to fix the problem by changing the transform matrix but I could not find a way. Maybe there is some pixel-to-matrix calculation?

Comment: This doesnt quite make sense. your image covers the entire container width & height = 100%. Are you saying you want css to modify the bottom right corner of your image? Please clarify the question so that we can better assist you.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. With image resizing I meant resizing the container.

Comment: maybe look into the `resize` style

Comment: `resize` style means that the user can resize the div. But I have to do it by code.